# If nothing sent to STDOUT in last x minutes, how to raise an error

Tags: ruby

I wonder if this is possible, because if it is, it would help me implement what I need for a program I am making:

Is there a way to attach some kind of listener to STDOUT from within a Ruby program, so that if nothing is written (via puts) to STDOUT for a certain time interval, an error is raised?

Writing to STDOUT should otherwise work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
 def new_puts(what)
  @time_th.kill if(@time_th)

  puts what
  @time_th = Thread.new() {
    sleep(2)
    raise "here"
  }
  @time_th.abort_on_exception = true
end

new_puts("test")
new_puts("test2")
sleep(10)

new_puts("test3") #too late
```

or with callback methods:

```
def callback
  puts "Timeout!"
end

def new_puts(what)
  @time_th.kill if(@time_th)

  puts what
  @time_th = Thread.new() {
    sleep(2)
    self.method(:callback).call
  }
end

new_puts("test")
new_puts("test2")
sleep(10)
new_puts("test3") #too late
```

Comment: Cool. One thing you might want is to do this in the usual hook style: `def ...; old=self.method(...); ...; end` this allows this method to be used with unmodified already written code.